# How to make two divs have the same position?

Tags: html, css, pug, css-position, visibility

I want to make two divs that have the size and position but only have one be visible at a time and be able to toggle between them.  I can position the second div using position:absolute but than the widths of the div aren't the same.  Is there a way to do this?  I might just be approaching the problem the wrong way.
This is what I have so far:

```
            div(class = "Control", id = "controlOne")
                div(id ="toggle")
                    input(type = "button",id = "pbtn", value = "one", onclick = "toggleTab('one');")
                    input(type = "button",id = "tbtn", value = "two", onclick = "toggleTab('two');")
            div(class = "Control", id = "controlTwo", style = "visibility: collapse")
                div(id ="toggle")
                    input(type = "button",id = "pbtn", value = "one", onclick = "toggleTab('one');")
                    input(type = "button",id = "tbtn", value = "two", onclick = "toggleTab('two');")  

    function toggleTab(tabID){
        if(tabID == "one"){
            document.getElementById("controlTwo").style.visibility = "collapse";
            document.getElementById("controlOne").style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("controlOne").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("controlTwo").style.visibility = "collapse";
        }
    }

#controlOne{
  height: 50%; 
  width: 50%;
}
#controlTwo{
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do it using absolute positioning here. Just create container with items and set `display: none` to items that you don't want to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append you're child `div`s in a main container and use CSS `position: relative`, then use `position: absolute` to child `div`s and add visibility to which `div` should be visible or not.

```css
.controlls {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.controll1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.controll2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="controlls">
  <div class="controll1">
    asd1
  </div>
  <div class="controll2">
    asd2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have a parent div as relative and the child as absolute.

There is a couple of problems with the code you posted:
- I can't see div "controlTwo"
- There are two divs with the same id "toggle"